# How do I decide which router should be DTE and DCE?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

When connecting two routers with a serial cable one end of the cable is always DTE and the other is DCE.
How do I decide which end I should connect to which router?
Does it even matter?
The worksheet that I'm doing doesn't specify any information regarding this. (At least not that I'm aware of)

[image]

Comment: Usually, the router in the higher tier is the DCE.

Comment: @Zac67 What do you mean by higher tier?

Comment: Higher in the hierarchy - closer to the network core.